# Get Contract Symbol from Transaction when multiple token transfers (swaps) in transaction occure

Tags: web3js, erc-20, ethereumjs

I want to monitor and extract the token transactions for a bunch of wallets using web3 subscriptions to the log events. I then extract the token information from the events contract.

My problem is, that I sometimes get the wrong symbol when multiple token transfers or swaps have been made like in the etherscan url below. I dont get BAT symbol but wETH using my function and therefore I get wrong dollarvalues.

For example when I extract the symbol for this transaction, I get thte symbol wETH instead of BAT.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd501dc1db9b185468012b2128238e034cfa96322112c93ed8b6f22f109f465e4

```
async getTokenInfo(address) {
    try {
        let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
        const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
        const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
        //const dollarPrice = this.getDollarPrice(symbol);
        const dollarPrice = await coingecko.getUSDPrice(symbol);
        return { symbol: symbol, decimals: decimals, dollarprice: dollarPrice };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('getTokenInfo', error.message);
    }
}

async getTokenAmount(tx, decimals) {
    try {
        let receipt = await this.getTransactionReceipt(tx);
        let decoded = await this.decodeLog(receipt);
        let eventName = decoded[0].name;
        let events = decoded[0].events;
        let amount = (events.find((e) => e.name == 'value').value / Math.pow(10, decimals)).toFixed(2);

        return amount;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('getTokenAmount', error.message);
    }
}
```